# Scrapy .css select element with a specific attribute name and value

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

How can Scrapy be used to select the text of an element that has a particular attribute name and value?

For example,

```
<span property="city">Montreal</span>
```

I tried the following but received a `None`

```
response.css('.span[property="city"]::text').extract_first()
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You are making a small mistake. You need to drop the `'.'` before `'span'`:

```
In [6]: response.css('span[property="city"]::text').extract_first() 
Out[6]: u'Montreal'
```